# Sql having count with related value

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some records like the below snap

```
s.no    cust_id     Balance id  amount
1       101         1           100
2       102         1           200
3       101         100         120
4       102         100         50
5       103         1           125
```

i want to get the records if balance id count >1. so I need the exact output like this.

```
s.no    cust_id     count       Balance 1   Balance 100
1       101         2           100         120
2       102         2           200         50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query

```
declare @tb table(s_no int,    cust_id int,    Balance_id int, amount int)
insert into @tb(s_no,cust_id,Balance_id, amount)values
           (1,101,1,100),
           (2,102,1,200),
           (3 ,101,100,120),
           (4,102,100,50),
           (5,103,1,125)

 ;with cte as
 (select cust_id,case when balance_id =1 then amount else 0 end as bls1,case when balance_id =100 then amount else 0 end as bls100 from @tb ) 
 select Row_number() over (order by cust_id) as srno,cust_id,count(*) as count,max(bls1) as [Balance 1],max(bls100) as [Balance 100] from cte  group by cust_id having count(*)>1
```